# What is the underlying system call to capture another program's graphical data?

Tags: windows, video-capture

Software like OBS and Discord both have the capability of capturing the graphical data of individual applications (even if they are not visible on screen). My question is what is the fundamental system call or API that allows them to do this?

Comment: Im interessted in this as well, as Ive tried automating on linux with virtual frame buffer, but obviously these things can be done on windows / mac